# When changing a range input's value, how do I change an element's css, based on its height?

Tags: jquery, html, css, height, onchange

Right now, I have some working JS that changes the height of a div depending on where the slider of a range input is. Since the height of the div is re-set each time the location of the range slider changes, I want to use the height of that div to then to also determine another element's background color.

Currently, this is the jQuery I have:

```
$("#range").change( function () {
  if ($("#mask").height() > 50) {
    $("#element").css("background-color", "#000000");
  }
  else {
    $("#element").css("background-color", "#ffffff");
  }
});
```

It partially works, but a main bug is coming into play: it only runs this change every other time I change the range input.

Is there a better or more accurate way to achieve this? What am I missing?

Comment: Could you provide some HTML, a jsFiddle perhaps?

Comment: Make sure you're setting the height of `#mask` before checking its height.

Comment: [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/xtn1s8st/1/)